# Magento 2.3 product image issue

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.2.7

Product image issue when upgrading Magento 2.2.7 to Magento 2.3.0.

I have two stores (id_1) and (id_2).

Issue (id_1): Category page is only [Magento 2 default product image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqQmC.jpg) for all products. No anything real product images for products. How fix this issue?

Tested and doesn't work:

- Command: bin/magento catalog:images:resize
- Clean image cache, var and static folder content
- Pub and media folder added permission 777

Comment: is issue resolve ?

Comment: There are maybe some invalid images in your product image list so when you run bin/magento catalog:images:resize, you find this error

Answer (score 0):

re-deploy **`static-content`** or if that doesn't work try deploying the **`sample data`** (again)

Comment: Doesn't work this also tested.

Comment: hmm this is an image path issue ..wait I'll get back to you

Comment: download this and unzip into your catalog/product folder
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RRKW3Nu64dA2brS-CMQf9Y3j39h7pIn_/view?usp=sharing
*back up the old product images files first before doing this
hope it helps

Comment: I don't have sample data. I have real products what i sell.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether there is any faulty picture in the folder. You also change the theme and run again the command resize.